How to handle big data from slack messages?
I currently have a slack app that fetches all the messages from all the public  channels in my workspace. After all the analysis, it posts the results to a specific slack channel. This app runs in an AWS Lambda using python. Lately, it has been throwing the following error:
slack.errors.SlackApiError: The request to the Slack API failed.
The server responded with: {'ok': False, 'error': 'ratelimited'}

I know this is related to the number of requests I make to the Slack API. I was thinking of using a fallback when I reach the rate limit. But, I don't like the idea of extending the life time of the lambda while it runs cause it would mean more money spent. Is there any other approach I can use to handle all this data without running out of my requests quota?
